# Why my code doesn't work for translate with gettext in php?

Tags: php, gettext, php-7.2

I use the `php version 7.2` with **gettext** extension installed .
I have created my `.po` file with POEdit and have `.mo` file with it.
I have added 1 translate in the file for testing it and respect the folder path needed.
My folder path `: Locale\en_US\LC_MESSAGES` from the root of my project.
Then I've created this follow code and translate doesn't work.
I have just every time:

> This is a text string!

But I need to retrieve :

> Translated!

I've tried to change the folder location, change some settings on POEdit, try to get information about function on test.php and they are fine apparently.
Trying to call different call method but doesn't work any Changement.

File in root: test.php

```
$Langue = "en_US";
$fest = putenv('LC_ALL='.$Langue);
$mest = setlocale(LC_ALL, $Langue);

$domaine = "messages";
$test = bindtextdomain($domaine, "./Locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES");
$pest = textdomain($domaine);

var_dump($fest);
var_dump($mest);
var_dump($test);
var_dump($pest);

echo _('This is a text string!');
echo "<br />";
echo gettext('This is a text string!');
```

File messages.po in : Locale\en_US\LC_MESSAGES\messages.po

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2019-08-07 12:14+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2019-08-07 13:02+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.2.3\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext\n"

# test1
msgid "This is a text string!"
msgstr "Translated !"
```

For dump of $fest

```
C:\wamp64\www\project\test.php:23:boolean true
```

For dump of $mest

```
C:\wamp64\www\project\test.php:24:string 'en_US'
```

For dump of $test

```
C:\wamp64\www\project\test.php:23:string 
'C:\wamp64\www\project\Locale\en_US\LC_MESSAGES'
```

For dump of $pest

```
C:\wamp64\www\project\test.php:24:string 'messages'
```

Comment: It's been a while I haven't work with gettext but I remember caching issues. Can you try to restart apache ? It might solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't make change , i have restart all serices , but no change appear .

Comment: And sorry for the question but can you confirm you generated the .mo file for your .po file ?

Comment: Yes i have it, same name than `messages.po` file : `messages.mo` at the same location on the **LC_MESSAGES** folder